# How to send json request to rails using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I would like to send JSON post request to rails 3 server. I have following ajax request:

`$.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',

                 contentType: "application/json",

                 url: url,
                 data: {email: "example@test.com", password: "password"},

                 success: onSuccess,

                 error: onError,

                 dataType: "json"

                 });`

However the rails server receive the data as following:

`{"_json"=>["object Object"]}`

Where I want it to receive it as:

`{"email"=>"exmaple@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}`

I think this is happening because the jquery wraps the data with _json object if the content type is json.

Does anybody know how I should do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be because of bugs in old version of jquery. I now user jquery version 1.5 and send post request as follow:

```
$.post(url, { email: emailVal, password: passwordVal }, callback, "json").error(errorHandler);
```

It now works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried doing the serialization yourself (using jQuery.param)?

```
jQuery.param({email: "example@test.com", password: "password"})
==> "email=example%40test.com&password=password"
```

So that your ajax request becomes:

```
$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
contentType: "application/json",
url: url, data: $.param({email: "example@test.com", password: "password"}),
success: onSuccess,
error: onError,
dataType: "json"
});
```

Comment: Actually, jquery serialize the passed data in default.

Comment: @knoguchi - yep - jQuery.param is what jQuery uses to serialize the object. I was just wondering if doing the serialization elsewhere (rather than .ajax doing it itself) would help solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried serialize manually as you suggested but it did not change anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

According to jquery docs it seems like if you pass in an object to data it will try some automatic deserialization.

Set `processData: false` and then set data to json string.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried not deserializing it but it wasn't the problem.